# Show that $f^2 - g^2 = C$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f$ and $g$ are continuously differentiable functions such that
$f(x) = g'(x)$ and $g(x) = f'(x)$ and any product of $f, g, f', g'$ is commutative for all $x \in \mathbb R$

I need to show that $f^2 - g^2 = C$ , where $C$ is a constant.

Logically this makes sense if you for example use a trig function $\sinh(x)$ but how can I show this to be true?

Comment: Use your knowledge about the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ to find the derivative of $f^2-g^2$

Comment: Actually, $f,g$ would not be sine and cosine, because $\sin'=\cos,\cos'=-\sin$. Instead, a pair of examples are $f=\sinh,g=\cosh$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that$$(f^2-g^2)'=2ff'-2gg'=2fg-2gf=0.$$